# Find all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(f(x+y)) = f(x)+f(y)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces, contest-math

The problem is to find the set of all functions $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $f(f(x+y)) = f(x)+f(y)$. 
 We first notice that $f(x)=x+c$ is a solution. With some work it turns out that it is enough to find solutions with $f(0)=0$ and from that to find all solutions, and moreover, it is not that hard to show that in this case of $f(0)=0$ the functional equation is equivilent to the two conditions: 
$$(1): f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y) \\ (2) :f(f(x))=f(x) $$
I was expecting that the only solutions will be $f(x) = x, f=0$ but with a bit more thought I think the set of solutions is bigger. I would like to know if I'm right. Here's what I thought: take a basis $\{e_\alpha\}_{\alpha \in I}$ of $\mathbb{R}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.
 Consider a division of this basis to disctint pairs $(e_\alpha, e_\beta)$ [each element of the basis appears in one and exactly one of those pairs). Define $f$ on the basis elements as $f(e_\alpha) = e_\beta, f(e_\beta)=e_\beta$. Thus we defined $f$ on the basis elements. Now, we simply continue $f$ linearly, to define it on all $\mathbb{R}$: $f(\sum a_i e_i) = \sum a_i f(e_i)$. This makes sure $(1)$ holds and $f$ is additive. By definition, it is trivial that $(2)$ also works if $x$ is a basis element,and therefore, because $f$ is additive, it also holds for any real number (just write it as a linear combination of the basis elements and do the algebra). Therefore I think this is a construction which shows that there are plenty of pathological solutions. Am I right? Is there a nice way to characterize all solutions?

Comment: As far as I can tell, your construction works. What's not clear is where you get the problem from.

Comment: It would be good if you explained your reduction of the problem to statements (1) and (2), as that isn't obvious to me. As for functions satisfying (1) and (2), there are a gazillion which are $\Bbb{Q}$-linear: e.g., pick any subset $A$ of your basis and define $f$ such that $f(a) = 0$ for any $a \in A$ and $f(x) = x$ for any other basis element. (Your construction is like this if you replace the $e_\alpha$s and $e_\beta$s by $e_\alpha + e_\beta$ and $e_\alpha - e_\beta$.)

Comment: @WhatsUp someone sent it to me.

Comment: @Omer Then there might not be a nice answer. I suggest that you recheck whether the statement is correct and confirm with the one who sent it to you that this is the intended question.

Comment: @RobArthan This is not an obvious reduction, it requires a number of steps. I didn't explain that because this wasn't very relevent to what I was trying to ask, which is if my construction is correct. However I believe the main difficulty is to make sure we can really assume $f(0)=0$, after that, you can plug $y=0$ to get (2), and after we know that (2) is true, by replacing $x$ by $x+y$ in it, the given becomes $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$, which is (1).

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3098231/determine-all-functions-fx-such-that-ffxy-fxfy and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196144/find-all-functions-f-bbbr-to-bbbr-such-that-f-is-continuous-and-ff?noredirect=1

Comment: @S.H.W: yes, the assumption that $f$ is continuous makes a lot of difference.

Comment: @WhatsUp I'll check that, you're probably right and that's a mistake in the problem.

Comment: In your comment you say that the main difficulty is "to make sure than we can really assume $f(0) = 0$", but you say that is "not hard to understand" in the question.

Comment: @RobArthan It probably wasn't the best choose of words, I wouldn't say it's hard, but it's not obvious and requires an observation or two. I'll edit the post

Comment: Your analysis is incorrect. You do not need distinct pairs. For example, $ f(x) = 0 $ maps to the pairing $(e_\alpha, 0)$ for all basis elements.

Answer (score 0):

Your analysis is incomplete.
You misunderstood what is necessary for $ f(f(x)) = x$.
While having $f(e_\alpha) = e_\beta, f(e_\beta) = e_\alpha$ is a sufficient condition, it is not a necessary condition. For example, the solution $f(x) = 0 $ corresponds to mapping each basis element to 0.

---

The first condition tells us that with any basis $ \{e_\alpha\}$ of $ \mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, if $ f( e_\alpha ) = f_\alpha$, then $ f(\sum a_\alpha e_\alpha) = \sum a_\alpha f_\alpha$.

The second condition tells us that the image of $f$ satisfies $ a \in $ Im $f \Rightarrow f(a) = a $.

So, the correct classification of solutions is:
Given any solution $f$,

- Let $ \{ e_\alpha\}$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$ basis for the image of $f$, then for every $a \in Im$  f, $ f(a ) = a$
- Let $\{e_\alpha\} \cup \{ f_\beta\}$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$ basis for $\mathbb{R}$. Then, $f( f_\beta) = \sum c_{\beta\alpha} e_\alpha$.
- Finally, if $ r = (\sum a_\alpha e_\alpha ) + (\sum b_\beta f_\beta)$, then $f(r) = (\sum a_\alpha e_\alpha )+ (\sum b_\beta c_{\beta\alpha} e_\alpha)$.

It is clear that any such solution satisfies the 2 conditions.

Comment: I didn't claim my analysis finds all solutions, I just wanted to make sure that it provides an example of a family of pathological solutions (that is, not f(x)=x or f=0).

Comment: I also agree that the usage of the word "incorrect" in this answer is incorrect. @CalvinLin Perhaps "incomplete" is a more suitable word.

Comment: K, I changed to incomplete.